# DFS Maze Generator

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a maze generating program, using a depth first search.  I have the following code, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to have X's in between to say which ones are walls.  But it's overwriting them, and putting paths right next to each other.  Any help would be great.  Below is the output.

```
. . . # # # # # # # 
. . . . # . . . . . 
. . . . # . # # # . 
. . # . # . . . # . 
. . # # # # # . # # 
. . . . # . . . # # 
. # # . # . # # # # 
. # # . . . # # # # 
. . . . . # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # 

import java.util.Random;

public class DepthFirstSearch {

    private Stack stack;
    public DepthFirstSearch() {}
    public char[][] DFS (int size, char[][] maze) {

        Random myRand = new Random();
        stack = new Stack(size);
        int x = myRand.nextInt(size);
        while (x % 2 == 0)
            x = myRand.nextInt(size);
        int y = myRand.nextInt(size);
        while (y % 2 == 0)
            y = myRand.nextInt(size);

        maze[x][y] = ' ';
        int total = (size * size) / 4;
        int visited = 1;
        int random[] = new int[4];
        int totalrand;

        while (visited < total) {
            totalrand = 0;
            if (x > 1 && maze[x - 2][y] == 'X')
                random[totalrand++] = 1;
            if (x < size - 2 && maze[x + 2][y] == 'X')
                random[totalrand++] = 2;
            if (y > 1 && maze[x][y - 2] == 'X')
                random[totalrand++] = 3;
            if (y < size - 2 && maze[x][y + 2] == 'X')
                random[totalrand++] = 4;

            if (totalrand > 0) {
                switch(random[myRand.nextInt(totalrand)]) {
                    case 1: maze[x-2][y] = maze[x-1][y] = ' ';
                            x -= 2;
                            stack.push(x * size + y);
                            visited++;
                            break;
                    case 2: maze[x+2][y] = maze[x+1][y] = ' ';
                            x += 2;
                            stack.push(x * size + y);
                            visited++;
                            break;
                    case 3: maze[x][y-2] = maze[x][y-1] = ' ';
                            y -= 2;
                            stack.push(x * size + y);
                            visited++;
                            break;
                    case 4: maze[x][y+2] = maze[x][y+1] = ' ';
                            y += 2;
                            stack.push(x * size + y);
                            visited++;
                            break;
                }
            }
            else {
                int vert = stack.pop();
                x = vert / size;
                y = vert % size;
            }
        }
        return maze;
    }

}
```

Comment: I originally had the maze as a character array, but I saw someone post elsewhere to make it a string and .equals() it.  But same results.

Comment: *(not an answer hence the comment)*...  By convention Java class names should start with an uppercase (*e.g.* you should have 'Stack' instead of 'stack') and methods with a lowercase, so you got it backwards.  Moreover having a class / constructor named "dfs" and a method names "DFS" and relying on case-sensitivity to differentiate them is confusing at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this works perfectly.  I was trying to be more efficient with my stack, and messed it up.  So with a working stack, it works perfectly.